# Binding [ngStyle] in Angular4 to ngModel or 2 way binding

Tags: javascript, angular, two-way-binding

I am trying to make one input box and add color to it. Same color should be added to the background of a paragraph. I am trying but getting error. Can someone help out?

**home.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="colorName"/>
<p [ngStyle]="{background-color:'colorName'}">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**home.ts**

```
  colorName: string = 'red';
```

> Note: I want to do this with [ngStyle] and 2-way binding only in
>   Angular4

Comment: change 
{background-color:'colorName'}
to {background-color:colorName}
remove the '. otherwise it will try to use the string colroName instead of your variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove quotos from `colorName` and add quotos in css property like this -

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="colorName"/>
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color':colorName}">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt6r3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color':colorName}">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add '' in `background-color`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="colorName"/>
<p [ngStyle]="{'background-color':colorName}">This is a paragraph.</p>
```